# The bounded buffer using semaphores in C

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

The following is the code I have so far. The program uses a buffer shared between two processes, a producer and a consumer. The producer reads characters from a file and places them in the buffer. The consumer reads each item from the buffer and prints the characters onto the screen. I run the program but it seems like it has run into an infinite loop or something that keeps it from terminating. Nothing gets printed to the screen and I don't see whats causing this.

```
#define _REENTRANT
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
typedef int bufferItem;
#define BUFFER_SIZE 5

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
sem_t full;
sem_t empty;
int counter;
bufferItem buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

//--------------------------------------------
// insert function used by producer thread
//--------------------------------------------
void insertItem(bufferItem item) {

  if (counter < BUFFER_SIZE) {
    buffer[counter] = item;
    counter++;
    return;
  } else
    printf("Error inserting item");
}

//--------------------------------------------
// remove function used by consumer thread
//---------------------------------------------
bufferItem removeItem() {

  if (counter > 0) {
    bufferItem itemRem;
    itemRem = buffer[counter - 1];
    counter--;
    return itemRem;
  } else
    return -1;
}

//---------------------------------------------
// producer prototype
//---------------------------------------------
void *thread1() {

  char newChar;
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("mytest.dat", "r");

  while (1 && fscanf(fp, "%c", &newChar) != EOF) {

    // produce an item
    bufferItem currentChar = newChar;

    sem_wait(&empty);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    insertItem(currentChar);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&full);
  }
  close(fp);
}

//---------------------------------------------
// consumer thread prototype
//----------------------------------------------
void *thread2() {
  while (1) {
    sem_wait(&full);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    bufferItem itemPrint = removeItem();

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&empty);
    printf("%d", itemPrint);

    sleep(1);
  }
}

//-------------------------------------------
// MAIN
//-------------------------------------------
main() {

  int r = 0;
  int i;
  sem_t sem1;
  int shmid;              /* shared memory ID */
  pthread_t tid1[1];      /* process id for thread 1 */
  pthread_t tid2[1];      /* process id for thread 2 */
  pthread_attr_t attr[1]; /* attribute pointer array */
  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
  sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
  sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
  counter = 0;

  fflush(stdout);
  /* Required to schedule thread independently.*/
  pthread_attr_init(&attr[0]);
  pthread_attr_setscope(&attr[0], PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);
  /* end to schedule thread independently */

  /* Create the threads */
  pthread_create(&tid1[0], &attr[0], &thread1, NULL);
  pthread_create(&tid2[0], &attr[0], &thread2, NULL);

  /* Wait for the threads to finish */
  pthread_join(tid1[0], NULL);
  pthread_join(tid2[0], NULL);

  printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
  printf("\t\t  End of simulation\n");

  exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now I can't say why it doesn't work, and I can't try your code because I'm on Windows. But first you should try do every possible error check. Check your fopen, pthread_create, pthread_join, etc...

(I don't think it will change anything, but it's a good practice to make your program more secure)

I will switch on my linux, so wait a bit :)

**EDIT:** Haha! It's in fact working since the beggining!
You have 2 solutions:

```
printf("%d\n", itemPrint);
```

or

```
printf("%d", itemPrint);
fflush(stdout);
```

The printf method bufferize before printing. It print only if:

- A '\n' is encountered
- The printf buffer is full
- The stdout is flushed

Also you can encounter problem with printf if you do:
`./your_program | cat -e` (which allow you to see non printable character), I don't really know why.

Answer (score 1):

1. it should be "fclose" from stdio rather than the "close" system call, which takes file descriptors not file pointers.
2. the producer runs alright, it's just that the output is all buffered because you didn't include a line break in the format string. flush it or add a line break and you'll see the output
3. there's no way for the consumer to terminate---it'll block indefinitely after the producer returns on the full semaphore

Out of curiosity, what platform and compiler is this for? GCC wouldn't compile it without modification.

Comment: I have sem_wait(full) in the consumer though. SHouldn't this keep the consumer from blocking?

Comment: @Flower
When the producer reaches the end of the file, it terminates. The consumer will consume the last of the items and block indefinitely when it counts the full semaphore past 0.

Comment: I have it now where the producer doesnt terminate when it reaches the EOF. But i still dont have anything printing.

Comment: @Flower
There are a few ways. What I like to do is have the producer put a "the end" token in the buffer, so the consumer will know it's done when it sees the token.

Comment: @Flower
Change the format string from "%d" to "%d\n", or add the line "fflush (stdout)" after the printf line

Comment: i added fflush(stdout) after my print statement in thread 2 but nothing has changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127013/discussion-between-user3109672-and-flower).